# When do we capitalize numbers or fractions?

Tags: capitalization, numbers

When do we have to capitalize numbers or fractions of a number or a quantity when writing them out like in

> Sie hatten erst **drei Viertel/drei viertel/Drei Viertel** des Weges zurückgelegt.
>   Es ist jetzt **viertel/Viertel** vor **zwölf/Zwölf** Uhr.
>   Wir treffen uns um **viertel/Viertel** nach **eins/Eins**.

Which version is correct? What are the rules that help me to decide when to capitalize?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct versions are:

> Sie hatten erst **drei Viertel** des Weges zurückgelegt.
>
> Es ist jetzt **Viertel** vor **zwölf** Uhr.
>
> Wir treffen uns um **Viertel** nach **eins**.

The [rules applying here](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/GrossKlein/pgf57-58.html) are:

- Cardinal numbers are written in lower case by default; they are capitalized only if used as nouns, denoting a digit ([Duden, Rule 78](https://web.archive.org/web/20120719120012/http://www.duden.de:80/rechtschreibregeln/gross-und-kleinschreibung#K78));
- Ordinal numbers and fractions have to be capitalized if used as nouns ([Duden, Rule 80](https://web.archive.org/web/20120719120012/http://www.duden.de:80/rechtschreibregeln/gross-und-kleinschreibung#K80)).

So the rule of thumb may be: **Cardinal numbers in lower case, fractionals capitalized.** But beware of the exceptions (only two examples here, there are many more…):

> Für den Teig benötigt man drei **viertel** Liter Milch... (*or:* drei Viertelliter)
>
> Er setzt all sein Geld auf die **Zwölf**.

Canoo has a [nice compliation of the rules about capitalisation of numbers](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Gross-klein/Zahlen.html) with hyperlinks to the respective "official" rules.

Answer (score 3):

Since "Viertel" is a noun, it is capitalized if used as such, this means if you could add an article, it is capitalized.

> Sie hatten erst drei Viertel des Weges zurückgelegt.

because you could write

> Sie hatten erst die drei Viertel des Weges zurückgelegt.

In the sentence

> Es ist jetzt Viertel vor zwölf.

you also could add an article:

> Es ist jetzt ein Viertel vor zwölf.

But according to new German orthography, "viertel" is not capitalized if you cannot add an article:

> Es ist jetzt viertel zwölf.

[Look here.](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/viertel)

In this sentence, "viertel" is used like a numeral.

Numerals, if used as such (and not f.ex. as a noun), are not capitalized (as in the sentences above).