# Warum keine Großschreibung einer Nummer, wenn sie als Subjekt benutzt wird?

Tags: spelling, capitalization, numbers

Zum Beispiel:

> Die ersten drei haben Bücher.

In diesem Fall ist "drei" ein Nomen. Warum beginnt es nicht mit einem großen Buchstaben?

Comment: Related [When should one capitalize adjectives/numerals which are used as noun?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/3401/1224)

Comment: Slightly related [When do we capitalize numbers or fractions?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/3223/1224)

Comment: Auch an dich der Hinweis, es ist ratsam erstmal abzuwarten und erst nach ein, zwei Tagen eine Antwort zu akzeptieren. Es kann immer noch sein, dass jemand anders eine bessere Antwort postet.

Comment: @Em1 Wenn jemand eine bessere Antwort postet, werde ich sie statt akzeptieren. Bis dann, deine ist gut und antwortet die Frage komplett.

Comment: Meiner Meinung nach ist die "drei" hier _kein_ Nomen, sondern das Nomen, auf das sie sich bezieht, wurde lediglich ausgelassen. "Die ersten drei [Schüler] haben Bücher".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Es kommt drauf an. [Canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Gross-klein/Zahlen.html) gibt einige Hinweise:

Allgemeine Regel:

> Zahlwörter schreibt man grundsätzlich klein. Wenn sie als Nomen verwendet werden, schreibt man sie groß.

Grundzahlen:

> Grundzahlen unter einer Million schreibt man klein, auch wenn sie die formalen Merkmale eines Nomens haben
>
> > Die ersten zehn in der Reihe können jetzt hineingehen.

Hintergrund dazu ist [Regel 58.6](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/GrossKlein/pgf57-58.html#pgf58-6). Paragraph 58 besagt:

> In folgenden Fällen schreibt man Adjektive, Partizipien und Pronomen klein, obwohl sie formale Merkmale der Substantivierung aufweisen.
>
> […]
>
> 6. Kardinalzahlen unter einer Million

Das bedeutet für Zahlen größer als eine Million:

> Zahlnomen werden großgeschrieben.

Und im Umkehrschluss zu folgender Aussage ([Getrennt- und Zusammenschreibung: Zahlen](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Getrennt-zusammen/Zahl.html?MenuId=SpellingRules024))

> Mehrteilige Kardinalzahlen unter einer Million werden zusammengeschrieben

ergibt das in Summe:

> Die anderen zwei Millionen siebenhundertfünfzigtausend haben Pech gehabt.

Spricht man aber beispielsweise von *der [hier ein Zahlwort einsetzen]*, ist es ein Nomen und gemäß der Regel *Nomen schreibt man groß* wird die Zahl tatsächlich großgeschrieben:

> Als Nomen verwendete Grundzahlen werden großgeschrieben, wenn sie eine Ziffer bezeichnen.
>
> > Sie hat dreimal hintereinander eine Sechs gewürfelt.

---

Ich habe hier nur die Regeln zitiert, die die Frage und Kommentare direkt betreffen. Es gibt noch einige weitere Regeln, wann ein Zahlwort groß- oder kleingeschrieben wird. Alle weiteren wichtigen Regeln zu dem Thema finden sich auf den verlinkten Seiten oder sind dort wiederum direkt verlinkt.

Comment: Man würde also schreiben "Die ersten hunderttausend haben Bücher", aber andererseits "Die übrigen Zweimillionen haben keine Bücher"? Ernsthaft?!

Comment: @AlexanderTobiasBockstaller Nein, sondern (wie auch in der Antwort erklärt): "Die übrigen zwei Millionen haben keine Bücher".