# Capitalization for numbers in German

Tags: capitalization, numbers

I've seen numbers like "hundert", "tausend", "hunderttausend" in German written in both upper and lower cases:

> **Upper case**: Hunderte von Menschen, einige Hundert Menschen
>
> **Lower case**: hunderte von Menschen, einige hundert Menschen

Is there a rule for when to use which one? What are the differences?

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3223/when-do-we-capitalize-numbers-or-fractions

Comment: @Takkat Can you merge both questions? The other answer links to canoo.net, and this link does answer this question.

Comment: @Em1: from the point of view of people finding this by Google it is much better to close as dupe (in case we agree that it really is a dupe) than to merge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the link to [canoo](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Gross-klein/Zahlen.html#Anchor-Wenn-44867) about capitalization of numbers (§58 E5) I translate and sumarize:

> When *hundert* and *tausend* represent an indeterminate number, which one cannot write with numbers, they could refeer to the numerals *Hundert* and *Tausend*. Accordingly they can be capitalized or not. For instance:
>
> - Es kamen viele tausende/Tausende von Zuschauern.
> - Mehrere tausend/Tausend Menschen füllten das Stadion