# Wird das Wort "eins" im folgenden Kontext groß- oder kleingeschrieben?

Tags: grammar, capitalization, standard-german

Ich schreibe gerade meine Seminararbeit und hänge gerade an folgendem Satz:

"Beim Event m erhöht […] den Wert […] an Stelle […] um den Wert eins."

Muss das "eins" in diesem Kontext groß- oder kleingeschrieben werden?

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3223/when-do-we-capitalize-numbers-or-fractions

Comment: Nebenbei würde ich nur »um eins« schreiben.

Comment: Ausserdem wäre der Satz vielleicht interessanter, wenn das Wort "Wert" nicht zweimal vorkäme. Vielleicht kannst du noch ein anderes Wort verwenden? Kommt natürlich auf den ganzen Satz an.

Comment: groß
man kann zum Beispiel keinen Artikel davor setzen

Comment: @mathiasmüller It wouldn't be even correct like this, would it? *einen Wert erhöhen um* needs a quantity, not another *Wert*

Comment: @embert That is true, in principle. Depends heavily on the context, though - and since we do not know the whole sentence all bets are off. For example, this sentence is acceptable: "Beim Event m erhöht sich der Wert der Variable X um den Wert eins." Mit anderen Worten, wenn nicht der "Wert" selber erhöht wird, sondern der Wert von etwas anderem, kann man auch "um einen Wert erhöhen".

Comment: I am currently writing a university homework about timestamping in distributed systems. The sentence was about vector time. Here is the full sentence:

`"Beim Event m erhöht P_2 seinen Wert nach Regel R_A2 an Stelle C_2 zuerst um den Wert eins."`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

§58 (6) der Rechtschreibregeln lautet:

> Kardinalzahlen unter einer Million [schreibt man klein, obwohl sie formale Merkmale der Substantivierung aufweisen]

Hierzu wird unter anderem folgendes Beispiel gegeben, das recht analog zu Deinem ist:

> Er sollte die Summe durch acht teilen.

Daher würde ich *eins* kleinschreiben.